# How to show that positive definite symmetric $nxn$ matrices are simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was told that they are "star-shaped" as a hint but would like to see how this is proven.

Comment: It is a good hint.  Do you have an intuition what matrix should be used as the "star point" of the region?  It would improve your Question if you make the body text more self-contained, not relying on the title to pose the problem.

Comment: @hardmath no I don't see it...

Comment: What the answer below outlines is that positive definite symmetric $A$ can be "path connected" to the identity matrix $I$.  So the set of positive definite symmetric matrices is "star-shaped" with respect to that "point".

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. If $A$ is symmetric, positive definite, show that for every $t\in [0,1]$
$$ A_t := (1-t)A + t \mathrm{Id} $$
also is.